# Como ler a informação da posição que o Cursor estiver no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Nos exemplos de Cursor que encontrei, para realizar a leitura da informação eu tenho que usar o comando: `FETCH NEXT FROM`

No meu código está assim: `FETCH NEXT FROM` **CURSOR1** `INTO` **@NOME** - na linha em que o Cursor estiver eu atribuo o dado encontrado a variável @NOME.

Com isso, estou com dois problema e talvez um deles não seja necessariamente um "problema".

**1º PROBLEMA**

Necessariamente acabo tendo que avançar para próxima linha toda vez que desejo capturar do dado onde o Cursor estiver. Há como realizar a leitura do Cursor independe de onde ele esteja?

**2º PROBLEMA (Talvez não seja um problema)**

Essa atribuição de valor a variável toda vez que avança para próxima linha deve consumir mais recurso do que o necessário. Por isso desejo atribuir o valor a variável somente após percorrer N posições e não a todo momento.

Comment: Dependendo do tipo de cursor, você pode [pular para uma posição específica](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/fetch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-declaring-a-scroll-cursor-and-using-the-other-fetch-options).

Answer (score 1):

Para que consiga realizar a leitura do Cursor sem necessariamente ter que passar linha a linha, basta utilizar o comando `FETCH ABSOLUTE` ao invés de `FETCH NEXT`,e logo em seguida o número da linha desejada, por exemplo, para acessar a linha 10: `FETCH ABSOLUTE` *10* `FROM` *CURSOR1*

É importante ressaltar que para usar qualquer argumento diferente de `NEXT` é obrigatório a especificação do `SCROLL` na declaração do Cursor. Exemplo: `DECLARE` CURSOR1 `SCROLL CURSOR FOR SELECT` *NOMES* `FROM` *[BASE_NOMES]*